# Persisting the state using local storage is not saving the state data for view type in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cookies, local-storage

Im trying to save the state of the listView, which is a boolean in my class component. The default value if listView is true. When it is true, it will render a listView and if false, it would not be. I have tried to research this out. I found that this can easily be dont with react hooks, however,there are so few examples for doing so with class components. The few examples that I have seen doing this in class components got me to try it out and implement something similar to my code. However, still after selecting another view and navigating away from the page or a page refresh, the state does not persist. Please see below:

Before implementation:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listView: true,
    };
  }



<ToggleButtonGroup className={classes.toggleButtonContainer} exclusive orientation="horizontal">
       <ToggleButton className={listView ? classes.selectedToggleButton : '' } selected={listView} onClick={() => this.setState({ listView: true })} value="list" aria-label="list">
         <Icon fontSize="large" color="default">view_list</Icon>
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton className={!listView ? classes.selectedToggleButton : '' } selected={!listView} onClick={() => this.setState({ listView: false })} value="module" aria-label="module">
                  <Icon fontSize="large" color="default">view_module</Icon>
                </ToggleButton>
         </ToggleButtonGroup>
```

After implementation:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      listView: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listView')) || []
    }
  }

 renderListView = (selection) => {
      ...

      this.setState({
        listView: selection
      },() => {
        localStorage.setItem('listView', JSON.stringify(this.state.listView))
      });
    }


 <ToggleButtonGroup className={classes.toggleButtonContainer} exclusive orientation="horizontal">
                <ToggleButton className={listView ? classes.selectedToggleButton : '' } selected={listView} onClick={() => this.renderListView(true)} value="list" aria-label="list">
                  <Icon fontSize="large" color="default">view_list</Icon>
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton className={!listView ? classes.selectedToggleButton : '' } selected={!listView} onClick={() => this.renderListView(false)} value="module" aria-label="module">
                  <Icon fontSize="large" color="default">view_module</Icon>
                </ToggleButton>
              </ToggleButtonGroup>
```

The local storage value is switching, but state is still going back to true after a page refresh

[image]

And here is the local storage showing another value when I toggle in local storage

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you check in the dev tools if the value in localStorage is set after you press the button?

Comment: Thanks and sure! Let me check

Comment: Yes it is, it switches when I switch view

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with your code. Could you add a `console.log(this.state)` at the end of the constructor? Maybe it will make the issue clearer.

Comment: Just guessing here but since listView is a boolean why are you setting your initial state like this: `listView: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listView')) || []`? If you have `listView:false` in localStorage that will result in the state being set to an empty array on every refresh, which will then evaluate truthy

Comment: Thanks guys! It was exactly what @lbsn mentioned the issue was!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ibsn perfectly diagnosed your problem.

JavaScript is pretty weird about handling types. Every value is considered ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), depending on whether they evaluate to `true` or `false`.

The `||` operator returns the first value if it is "truthy" and the seconds if it isn't.

In your case the first value can have 3 possible values: `null` if you have never pressed the button and `true` or `false` if you have pressed it before.

Usually the `||` operator would work perfectly to differentiate between for example and object and `null`, but here, both `null` and `false` are "falsy", thus the `false` value is replaced by the empty array `[]`, which is "truthy". This leads to the  value in localStorage to be ignored.

There are a couple of ways to fix the problem. The one I would recommend is explicitly checking if the value in the localStorage is `null`.

```
const storageValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("listView"));
this.state = {
    listView: storageValue !== null ? storageValue : true,
};
```